# Jquery get value from json on ajax complete

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Maybe i missing something but i can't get the value from json

The code i use to get the json output is:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/?ids=ga%11111111&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&fields=totalsForAllResults&access_token=',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'data',
        complete: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The output is:

```
{"totalsForAllResults":{"rt:activeUsers":"3"}}
```

I want to get the the number "3"

Thanks

Comment: Replace `dataType: 'data'` with `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Hi @ JCOC611 i have change datatype to json i tried to get the value but still not luck. can you provide code that get the number from "rt:activeUsers"

Comment: Does the Google APIs URL accept requests from third party sources? If not you may be blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON.parse(data)` and get a javascript object from the json, or change your request datatype to json.

Comment: Hi @BKR i have change datatype to json i tried to get the value but still not luck. can you provide code that get the number from "rt:activeUsers"